# Jquery check if i tag has a class and replace it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html structure:

```
<ul class="list-inline recommended-logo">
    <li><i id="icon-changer" class="First class"></i><span>First class</span></li>
    <li><i id="icon-changer" class="Second class"></i><span>Second class</span></li>
    <li><i id="icon-changer" class="Third, class"></i><span>Third, class</span</li>
    <li><i id="icon-changer" class="Four class"></i><span>Four class</span></li>
</ul>
```

How I can check with jQuery if any of this classes exist and if exist then replace with different text classes. In the same page can be more than 3 classes.

I try to create something like this but is work only for first class:

```
if (jQuery("#icon-changer").hasClass("First class")) {
    jQuery('#icon-changer').removeClass(First class').addClass('icon-first');
}
if (jQuery("#icon-changer").hasClass("Second class")) {
    jQuery('#icon-changer').removeClass('Second class').addClass('icon-second');
}
```

here is how my html is generated:

```
   foreach($targetValues as $_target) :?>
     <ul class="list-inline recommended-logo">

     <li><i id="icon-changer" class="<?php echo $_target ?>"></i><span><?php echo $_target ?></span></li>
     </ul>
    <?php endforeach;
```

Comment: Find `$( ".class" ).length`

Comment: Why are you reusing IDs? Why aren’t you using common classes for all `<i>` elements? What have you tried? You have already named both steps: “check if element has a class”, “replace elements’ classes” (or so). Where exactly are you stuck in accomplishing these two steps?

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Comment: You can use `.hasClass()`

Comment: replace to what? In you example you have 4 different classes. Should these be changed to something else?

Comment: You have previous questions where your code selects by class and also changes text content, so what's the problem here?

Comment: yes for example for the First class I need to be replaced with icon-one, Second class with icon-two

Comment: I edit my question and I add what I try

Comment: all that classes that are initial in the html are generated automatically, for that I want to use something like find and search, so I can't change anything in the intial html

Comment: first of all according to html specification, you cant use the same ID twice.
Your HTML structure is broken, fix it, then your jquery should work well

Comment: we can remove the ID, I just put the ID there just to be much easy to call. so what is the solution? why the html is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE::
You could try something equivelant:

```
<ul class="list-inline recommended-logo">
    <li><i id="icon-changer" class="First class"></i><span>First class</span></li>
    <li><i id="icon-changer" class="Second class"></i><span>Second class</span></li>
    <li><i id="icon-changer" class="Third class"></i><span>Third, class</span></li>
    <li><i id="icon-changer" class="Fourth class"></i><span>Four class</span></li>
</ul>

<script>
   var arr = [{class:'First.class',id:'first'},{class:'Second.class',id:'second'},{class:'Third.class',id:'third'},{class:'Fourth.class',id:'fourth'}]
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;++i){
    $(`.${arr[i].class}`).parent().find('span').text(`${arr[i].id}`)
//Or if what you need is to change the class name to the name of the id
//$(`.${arr[i].class}`).removeClass().toggleClass(`icon-${arr[i].id}`)
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I can't change the classes, the html must remain intact

Comment: updated, but doesnt make a difference. Should still be what you needed?

Comment: but you here change the id? I need to replace the First class with icon-class1 for example

Comment: run the code in jsfiddle and you can see the id is changed to represent the class

Comment: I need to change the text inside the class not the ID, only First class with icon-class1

Comment: Hi I think is something good, but there are some issues, first I don't need to change the span text, I need to change the class for tag i, so if the span have First class then the i class will be first_class and two if you take a look at the third li there in the span there we have the class with comma: class="Third, class" how we can put this comma in your javascript?

Comment: I think I solve it, with your code it seems to be perfect

Answer (score -3):

First of all, make sure your class names do NOT have spaces. Spaces in `class="a b"` actually means 2 separate classes, a and b, not a class "a b". Also as others have mentioned, IDs should be unique. So with code:

```
<ul class="list-inline recommended-logo">
    <li><i id="icon-changer-1" class="first_class"></i><span>First class</span></li>
    <li><i id="icon-changer-2" class="second_class"></i><span>Second class</span></li>
    <li><i id="icon-changer-3" class="third_class"></i><span>Third, class</span</li>
   <li><i id="icon-changer-4" class="fourth_class"></i><span>Four class</span></li>
</ul>
```

You can select by class (with a .) and replace easily:

```
$('.first_class').removeClass('first_class').addClass('fifth_class')
```

will take everything with the class "first_class" and replace it with "fifth_class".

I stand by my original code as listed above. But looking at the edits to the question, the problem is apparently using jQuery to select on ID when IDs are repeated - the first  So **ignore** the IDs and select based on the classes - that is, use `$('.First')` `$('.Second')` etc. for each of the removeClass/addClass function calls. $('#...') simply won't work as expected if IDs are not unique.

Comment: please take a look at my classes, that text with spaces and how it look there must be replaced, I can;t change the default classes

Comment: @RobertD - I'm not quite sure what you are saying. Why can't you change the default classes? You can run jQuery on the page but can't change the HTML???

Comment: I edit my post, you can take a look in that foreach to understand for what I can't change that classes

Comment: @RobertD - That PHP code is really messed up. You should never have a static ID being used in a loop - that guarantees duplicate IDs which is a real problem.